# WPF: Create box with text in four corners

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, I'm trying to create a button with four labels at each corner.  It would look like a dice (die?) with text in the corners instead of dots.

This code doesn't work:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" Height="100" >
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition/>                               
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>                                                
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="TopLeft"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="TopRight" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="BottomLeft"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="BottomRight" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
</Button>
```

It mashes the text into the center of the grid instead of moving it to the corners.  It seems like the grid is not taking up all the space in the button.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `VerticalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` for the Button to Stretch.

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" Height="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="TopLeft"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="TopRight" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="BottomLeft" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="BottomRight" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```